# VS 2022. Multiple projects importing same shared project causes type errors (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

I have 3 projects import same Shared project (via Add Link), which then imports all those 3 projects (Add Link again).

[image]

There is a

```
public class Pin
{
...
    public enum PinState {...}
}
```

in Shared. And if I use this enum in Driver's projects it's fine (`using Shared.Models`), but when I try to use it in ObjectCollector (same `using Shared.Models`) project I get errors like this.

[image]

I've tried

```
using PinS = Shared.Models.Pin.PinState;
Device.Pins[0].SetPinState(PinS.High);
```

but i still get same error.

I've tried removing ObjectCollector's Link to Shared, but it results in CS0433 "Ambiguous reference".

Comment: You cannot do this like this.... Shared have to be library not only source of code source

Comment: Yes, for the `Shared` code you need to use a Class Library for this, not a Shared Project.

Comment: Assumption you have library 1 library 2 both using shared source.. So if you are are using l1 and l2 in another project classes from shared are different as they come from different assemblies(they are compiled in both)... Being class with the same name and namespace is not enough